# How to pass ID parameter from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, button, parameters

I am having trouble passing the ID value to the controller method in the input submit button. I am trying to pass the ActionItemID value depending on which row the user clicks the O button. I can't seem to call the value in the controller.

```
@model SQLApplication.Models.ActionItems.ActionItemsViewModel

    <table class="table table-condensed table-action-items">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.Status)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.Principal)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.CompanyName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.ActionItem)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.Owners)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.DueDate)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.UpdatedDate)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.CreatedDate)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description.Sales)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Principal)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ActionItem)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owners)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedDate)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sales)</td>

            <td class="right"><input type="submit" name="O" value="@item.ActionItemId" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Open", "ActionItems")'" /></td>
            <td class="right"><input type="submit" value="P" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ActionItems")'" /></td>
            <td class="right"><input type="submit" value="C" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ActionItems")'" /></td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: How does your action method signature looks like  ? You can use the Url.Action overload to pass route params. `Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", new { id=item.ActionItemId })`

Comment: And then the action method signature would look like
         public ActionResult Open(int? id)
        {

            using (var db = new SJAMsSynchMetroEntities())
            {
                tblActionItem ai = db.tblActionItems.Find(id);
                ai.Status = "open";
            }
} and id would be the id value? it's showing up as 0 and there are no action items with a 0 as an id

Answer (score 0):

There are no values in the redirect you're performing:

```
location.href='@Url.Action("Open", "ActionItems")'
```

If you want an `id` value included, add it to the `Url.Action` method call:

```
location.href='@Url.Action("Open", "ActionItems", new { id = item.ActionItemId })'
```

It does look like you're trying to use a `value` attribute, which itself would be useful in a `<form>` being submitted by your submit button.  But I suspect that, without a `<form>`, your button wasn't doing anything so you added the JavaScript redirect.  Either way works, really.  The key differences would be:

- A redirect like this is only ever a GET request, never a POST.  If you need POST, use a form or perhaps AJAX and a redirect when it completes.
- Most of the time users have JavaScript enabled and this isn't a concern.  But *sometimes* it is, such as for accessibility needs.  Make sure it's okay that you can rely on your users using JavaScript.